# Is biblatex compatible with RevTeX?

Tags: biblatex, natbib, incompatibility, revtex

`biblatex` seems to be not compatible with RevTeX. As RevTeX automatically loads `natbib`, I load `biblatex` with the option `natbib=true`, but still LaTeX compiler complains that lot of commands are already defined. I make them undefined as follows:

```
\let\bibhang=\undefined
\let\citename=\undefined
\let\textcite=\undefined
\let\bibfont=\undefined
\let\Citeauthor=\undefined
\let\citet=\undefined
\let\citep=\undefined
\let\citealt=\undefined
\let\citealp=\undefined
\let\Citet=\undefined
\let\Citep=\undefined
\let\Citealt=\undefined
\let\Citealp=\undefined
\let\citefullauthor=\undefined
\let\citetext=\undefined
\let\defcitealias=\undefined


but still obtain various errors such as

! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.78 \begin{document}

?
```

I've checked that `natbib` compatibility mode is switched on:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load natbib compatibility...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-natbib.def' found.
 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\blx-natbib.def"
File: blx-natbib.def 2011/02/13 v1.2a biblatex natbib compatibility
```

So, it looks as if that trouble comes from RevTeX. I tried both RevTeX4 and more recent RevTeX4-1. No difference.

Comment: The `biblatex` manual states that `natbib` is incompatible with `biblatex`. The `natbib` option is unrelated to the package (it emulates it, but doesn't make it compatible).

Comment: Since you have a response below that seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count. This shows which answer helped you most if there's more than one answer, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on how difficult implementing a fork of RevTeX 4.1 that would be compatible with biblatex would be? I'd be prepared to put a bounty on it. As Igor mentions in the comment in the answer by Lockstep, this class dominates physics.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37077/315817) gives a hack to use `biblatex` under RevTeX. (Answerd by Joseph Wright, the author of `biblatex-phys`.) You probably want to augment it by [`biblatex-phys`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys) package in CTAN, as [pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12047/is-biblatex-compatible-with-revtex#comment1708178_12051) by [minmax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/171295/minmax).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since `biblatex` "reimplements the bibliographic facilities of LaTeX from the ground up, [it] naturally conflicts with all packages modifying the same facilities" (manual, section 1.5.4). Specifically, `biblatex` is incompatible with `natbib`. `biblatex`' `natbib` option only provides aliases for `natbib`'s citation commands.

From a look into the manual of RevTeX 4.1, `natbib` is a required package, and multiple custom options and commands are defined on top of `natbib`. So no, I'm afraid `biblatex` is incompatible with RevTeX.

Comment: That's pity. RevTeX is obligatory document class for all APS journals and most journals on physics wolrdwide.

Comment: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys/biblatex-phys.pdf seems to be a solution.

Comment: @simd the link is broken; could you update it?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys

Comment: Appreciate the help and creation of biblatex-phys, but this is inoffical to use with RevTeX, or in other words, it looks like a good hack.