# Is it possible to load biblatex with a class that has already loaded natbib?

Tags: biblatex, natbib, incompatibility, revtex

A while ago I asked [a meta question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2027/9043) on how big a question can be. I was wondering in particular about breaking open `REVTeX` and reorganising the goo within to replace the `natbib` bits with bits that play more nicely with `biblatex`. This would surely be a large undertaking. Joseph Wright pointed out that

- [This is probably a bad idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/9043) (`REVTeX` produces a pretty funky `bbl` file and it's difficult to tell how important the internals of that are to the publisher).
- A better question would be about getting `biblatex` to work when `natbib` is around too.

As the second point proposes a question of broader relevance than the one I originally intended to ask, and there is the possibility of a solution that would require much less effort than rewriting a class, I'm asking it here. Essentially I'd be using a solution just for my own notes, which often get remixed into papers in a REVTeX class, so for publication I'd have to default to the standard way. It's a start though! So:

**Is it possible to load `biblatex` with a class that has already loaded `natbib`?**

The first error can be produced with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps,pra]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\author{Mark S.\ Everitt}
\pacs{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
stuff

\end{document}
```

and the error is:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty:382: LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Comment: I don't think that there's much to do about this, as RevTeX depends heavily on **natbib** features. There are 29 lines in `revtex4-1.cls` where a control sequence of the form `\NAT@...` appears and it seems quite complicated to correct things in such a way that **biblatex** can substitute **natbib**.

Comment: @egreg: I think that you're as far as REVTeX goes. For other classes or packages that rely on natbib, it's going to have to be judged for each. I'm going to finally give up on this for now. :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Working with the assumption here that we are simply trying to ignore `natbib` entirely, all that needs to happen is that the various name clashes need to be dealt with. Setting up a demo where `natbib` is deliberately loaded before `biblatex`, it seems that the macros `\bibhang`, `\citename`, `\bibfont` and `\Citeauthor` need to be undefined. At the same time, it's necessary to deal with `\ver@natbib.sty`, which is the internal macro LaTeX uses to track the fact that `natibib` has been loaded. It's this macro that `biblatex` uses in `\@ifpackageloaded` to issue a warning about `natbib`. Thus the following builds fine for me:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Test,
  journal = "J. Irrep. Res.",
  author  = "Other, A. N.",
  year    = "2011",
  title   = "Some things I did"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
% Start of 'ignore natbib' hack
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax
% End of 'ignore natbib' hack
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

To get things working with REVTeX, I find that I also need to undefined `\textcite`. There is then a second issue, as REVTeX alters the definition of `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase`. Thus I've copied the originals from `latex.ltx` and restored them:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Test,
  journal = "J. Irrep. Res.",
  author  = "Other, A. N.",
  year    = "2011",
  title   = "Some things I did"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{revtex4}
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\let\textcite\relax
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{{%
      \def\i{I}\def\j{J}%
      \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##1##2\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\uppercase{#1}}%
      \reserved@a
   }}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MakeLowercase}[1]{{%
      \def\reserved@a##1##2{\let##2##1\reserved@a}%
      \expandafter\reserved@a\@uclclist\reserved@b{\reserved@b\@gobble}%
      \protected@edef\reserved@a{\lowercase{#1}}%
      \reserved@a
   }}
\makeatother
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(The changes are actually to internal macros used by robust commands, so simply coping using `\let` before the document class line will not work here without some extra effort.)

For REVTeX 4.1, it seems you need

```
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{}
```

after `\begin{document}` as REVTeX tries to use it at the end of the document, which gives an error with `biblatex`.

Comment: I've set this up as a minimal demo: the question seems to ask about the general case, and so I've gone for something less complex than REVTeX as a test case.

Comment: This code works fine, but I still want to tackle REVTeX. I took your natbib hack and put it in between the `documentclass` and the `usepackage`. After a couple of extra `undefines` I hit a wall with the error `Package biblatex Error: Patching \MakeUppercase failed.` and a similar one for `\MakeLowercase`. Any ideas?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt See my edit: I was just sorting that out!

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! Sorry for jumping the gun there. I'll give that a test. BTW, is it necessary to explicitly load `natbib`? `REVTeX` should do it for you.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I'll edit to remove that: I'd forgotten about it.

Comment: This all comes with a big health warning: I've no idea how it will work with the rest of REVTeX. It also reminds me I'm supposed to be sorting out some physics styles for `biblatex`!

Comment: Just one more issue... You're using REVTeX4, and I'm using REVTeX4-1. There's unfortunately a fairly big difference.

Comment: I'd vote you up more if I could!

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: You could spend an after-the-fact bounty. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: I think  bounties are good for getting attention only. Having said that, if you have a solution that you're holding hostage, I'm willing to negotiate of course! ;)

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks for this solution. REVTeX4-1 is a bit of a beast, and probably far too tied to natbib. Even if the errors can be killed, it's likely to cripple REVTeX. Oh well! I was going to be stuck with BibTeX anyway!

Comment: @JosephWright This works, but the styling of bibliography numbering is changed and the end of text references are no longer shown with reference number in square brackets. How can I remedy that?