# Biblatex with classicthesis. \bibhang already defined

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, classicthesis

I've an issue with the bibliography in `classicthesis`. My main.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}                    

%Loaded here: microtype,graphicx,booktabs,caption,tabularx,hyperref,amsmath
\usepackage{myclassicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\bibliography{references}

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

My references.bib:

```
@manual{label,
author= {myauth},
editor= {myedit},
title=  {mytitle},
date=   {2011}
}
```

Here [`myclassicthesis-preamble`](http://baduel.altervista.org/stackoverflow/myclassicthesis-preamble.sty).

Finally the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
[...]
l.637 \newlength{\bibhang}
?
```

Problably there is something already defined in `myclassicthesis-preamble`, but I don't know what.

I use TeXworks in Windows 7 x64.

Comment: The package `myclassicthesis-preamble` loads `natbib`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37076/is-it-possible-to-load-biblatex-with-a-class-that-has-already-loaded-natbib

Comment: @JosephWright The question is the same, but the answer is not clear for me, sorry.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on where the special preamble file comes from. It seems to be a some settings which show off `classicthesis`, but which really are just part of the preamble and should simply be copied into place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The file `myclassicthesis-preamble.sty` loads `natbib`; if you are not going to use any of the features of `natbib`, open the file and comment out, or delete, the lines

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,numbers}{natbib}
 \RequirePackage{natbib}                % NB: LyX likes to set natbib too, let's avoid clashes
```