# Showing Title of article with chem-angew biblatex style?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chem

first of all: I am new to Latex so please be patient if I do not get complex answers at first. I have not yet defined my own commands and such things. Thus I would be very happy over every detailed answer! Thank you in advance.

My problem:
I am writing a report and my superviser wants the bibliography in the chem-angew style. However, he wants the titles and issue-numbers also. But they are not shown in this minimal example that I wrote:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,listof=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,hyperref=true,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{My_EndNote_Library.bib}
\bibliography{My_EndNote_Library}

\begin{document}

\cite{RAFT-instruction}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered] 

\end{document}
```

As I said: I have never medled with a package so far... how can I make biblatex to show the title of articles and the issue number? The title shall be shown after the names. The issue numer after the Volume and the issue number shall be in brackets like this: (3)

I found this line in google:

```
\setkeys{chem-angew}{articletitle=true}
```

However, it does not work. It says articletitle undefined.

My .bib:

```
@article{
RAFT-instruction,
   Author = {Chen, Senbin and Binder, Wolfgang H.},
   Title = {Controlled copolymerization of n-butyl acrylate with semifluorinated acrylates by RAFT polymerization},
   Journal = {Polym. Chem.},
   Volume = {6},
   Number = {3},
   Pages = {448-458},
      Year = {2015} }
```

Thank you very much for your attention!
Greetings

My whole preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{rsc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup{labelsep=period,labelfont=bf}%damit in Beschriftungen x.x. steht anstatt x.x und damit fett
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,hyperref=true,style=chem-angew,articletitle=true]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float} %macht, dass schema möglich sind
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % fette Schrift unter Figure und anderen Floats

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref} %damit Schema im Text richtig bezeichnet
```

Edit: Thank you for your help already. However, on a second look I noticed that the issue number is not in brackets plus there is a comma in front of it... can one get rid of this too? it should look like this:

author, title. *journal name* **year,** *Volume* (Issue), frompage-topage

Comment: _Angewandte Chemie_ (along with most other chemistry journals) does not print the issue: that's why it's not there!

Answer (score 2):

### Add journal titles

To add the article titles to your bibliography you just have to add `articletitle=true` to the options of `biblatex`. The following is a full MWEB with that option included.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,listof=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,hyperref=true,style=chem-angew,articletitle=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{
RAFT-instruction,
   Author = {Chen, Senbin and Binder, Wolfgang H.},
   Title = {Controlled copolymerization of n-butyl acrylate with semifluorinated acrylates by RAFT polymerization},
   Journal = {Polym. Chem.},
   Volume = {6},
   Number = {3},
   Pages = {448-458},
      Year = {2015} }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{RAFT-instruction}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered] 

\end{document}
```

Please also note that I have removed `\bibliography{My_EndNote_Library}` as this is a `bibtex` command, while you are using `biblatex`.

### Add issue numbers

To be able to add print the issue numbers, I have copied and modified the corrensponding `BibliographyDriver` from `chem-angew.bbx`. 
You just need to add the following code to the preamble of your docment.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

In comparison to the original code, I have added `\printfield{number} \newunit`.

### Edit: no comma before issue number in parenthesis

In order to achieve the format you requested in your edit, you could replace the above witten code by the following.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{(#1)}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit 
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \newunit
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

`\DeclareFieldFormat...` ensures that the issue number is written in parentheses. 
`\renewbibmacro...` adds the issue number without printing a comma between volume and issue, but a space. If you want to remove the space, just remove the following `\setunit*{\addspace}%` between the two `\printfiled` commands.

```
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The example does work. However, as soon as I introduce the change in my whole file it says 'Command \bibhang already defined. Or name \end... illegal'. what does that mean and how can i get rid of it? I would post my pereamble but i do not have enough characters here...

Comment: Do you load the `natbib` package in your preamble? According to the following links, both packages are incompatible. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37296/134144
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37076/134144

Comment: I did not load the natbib individually... I set it to 'true' though. but this ws done in the minimal example as well. i managed to add my peamble now in the original post if this helps.  As soon as i solved this issue i will try to introduce the next (the numbers) :) thank you already so much

Comment: In the preable you posted in your question, you load the `rsc`package. This is basically is a collection of `bibtex`styles and seems to load the `natbib` package in the background. As you are using `biblatex` and not `bibtex` you do not need the `rsc` package at all. Removing it should solve the above mentioned problem.