# First initials only in elsarticle (biblatex incompatible)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, elsarticle

I have bib files with a mixture of full first names and first initials only (and the same for middle names). I have to submit a paper in elsarticle now and would like to make this consistently first initial only. I have seen solutions that require you to edit the style file (see e.g. http://jonmccune.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/first-initials-only-in-bibtex/) and in `biblatex` you just set `firstinits=true` it seems. My problems are twofold. I don't think I am allowed to edit the `elsarticle` style file for submission and it seems `biblatex` and `elsarticle` are incompatible. If I try to use biblatex I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}

\section{}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Is it possible either to use `biblatex` in a way which keeps the `elsarticle` styling unchanged or to use `bibtex` and get first initials only without editing the style file?

Comment: If you're using `elsarticle` for submission, it is *not* a good idea to use `biblatex`, since `elsarticle` requires `natbib`, and your publisher will not appreciate the change. (Comment mainly added for others who might see the question.)

Comment: See the answer and 'health warning' to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37076/is-it-possible-to-load-biblatex-with-a-class-that-has-already-loaded-natbib

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that using `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}` for example, you get first initials only as required.