# How to rebuild the textcite command from biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, natbib

Unfortunately I have to use a document class (egpubl version 3.57) which seems not to be compatible with biblatex. Although I tried to nihilate the declaration of a bibhang ([cf similar natbib question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37076/is-it-possible-to-load-biblatex-with-a-class-that-has-already-loaded-natbib)), biblatex complained of beeing incompatible with backref. Further investigation showed, that it seems to be an conflicting option of the hyperref package. So I gave up and have to use the cite package.

Whenever I type now a citation I do this like this:

```
... as shown in Feirrera~et~al.~\cite{Ferreira2013}. ...
```

I started to create a macro like this:

```
\newcommand{\multicite}[2]{#1~et~al.~\cite{#2}}
```

Which renders to this:

```
... as shown in \multicite{Feirrera}{Ferreira2013}. ...
```

Is there an easy way to get the family name from the bibkey of the first author?

My MWE is currently like this:

```
\documentclass{egpubl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibl.bib}
@book{Some2005,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some and Other, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\WsSubmission
 \electronicVersion
 \PrintedOrElectronic

% % This are my attempts to load biblatex nonetheless
%\let\bibhang\relax
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{cite}

\title[foo]{bar}
\author[A. Barfoo]
       {A. Barfoo$^{1}$\\,
         $^1$Foobar institute\\
       }
\newcommand{\multicite}[2]{#1~et~al.~\cite{#2}}

\begin{document}

as shown in \multicite{Some}{Some2005}

\bibliographystyle{eg-alpha-doi}
\bibliography{bibl.bib}

\end{document}
```

- [egpubl.cls](http://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~math/tmp/egpubl.cls)
- [eg-alpha-doi.bst](http://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~math/tmp/eg-alpha-doi.bst)
- [paper.tex](http://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~math/tmp/paper.tex)

Comment: Imho it is probably easier to avoid the conflict with backref whatever it is. One can always fool latex so that it doesn't load a package. But as you didn't provide a minimal example for tests .... Beside this: natbib has the command `\citet`. Doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: I was wrong that the class is using natbib. I will change this in the question. It was an already defined \bibhang which is also used by natbib. I will produce a minimal example (which involves the egpubl class as well.

Comment: You cannot use a `.bst` file with `biblatex`....

Answer (score 2):

You can use biblatex like this:

```
\documentclass{egpubl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\let\bibhang\arealyundefinedcommand
\usepackage{biblatex}

\WsSubmission

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\electronic@Version}{%
   \usepackage[pdftex,
    %pagebackref=true,
    colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarks=false,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    pdftitle={\@shorttitle},
    pdfauthor={\@shortauthor},
    pdfsubject={\pdf@Subject},
    pdfkeywords={Computer Graphics Forum, EUROGRAPHICS}]{hyperref}
  }
\renewcommand{\printed@Version}{%
   \usepackage[pdftex,
    %pagebackref=false,
    colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,
    bookmarks=false,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    pdftitle={\@shorttitle},
    pdfauthor={\@shortauthor},
    pdfsubject={\pdf@Subject},
    pdfkeywords={Computer Graphics Forum, EUROGRAPHICS}]{hyperref}
  }  
\makeatother  
\electronicVersion
\PrintedOrElectronic

% % This are my attempts to load biblatex nonetheless
%\usepackage{cite}

\title[foo]{bar}
\author[A. Barfoo]
       {A. Barfoo$^{1}$\\,
         $^1$Foobar institute\\
       }
\newcommand{\multicite}[2]{#1~et~al.~\cite{#2}}
\addbibresource{bibl.bib}
\begin{document}

as shown in \cite{Some2005}, \textcite{Some2005} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your work, I wasn't aware how to ommit the backref parameter inside of the usepackage stmt of the hyperref package. However, as jon already mentioned, the alphabetic style is somehow different from the eg-alpha-doi.bst style. with style=alphabetic I get a similar start, however, I don't know how to change the rest, and I think I have to deal with the cite package and type everywhere the et~al.~ where I need to.. But again thank you for your work.