# Citations using biblatex together with Tufte style are producing weird results

Tags: biblatex, citing, tufte

I'm having some problems with the citations in the Tufte class. I have several questions related to this which i will post below, but first i will provide a minimum working example, test.tex:

```
\documentclass[nohyper,nobib,nofonts]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[american]{babel}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{testBib.bib}  
\usepackage{hyphenat}  
\usepackage{csquotes}  

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}  
Some text~\autocite{bobylev}.  
\section{section}  
Lots and lots of more text~\autocite{Zhong}.  
\subsection{subsection}  
Delicious yummy text~\autocite{xu2004}. OmNomNom~\autocite{Lockerby}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And a simple bibliography testBib.bib:

```
@article{bobylev,
 author = {Bobylev, A. V.},
 title = {The Chapman–Enskog and Grad methods for solving the
 Boltzmann equations},
 journaltitle = {Soviet Physics - Doklady},
 number = {27},
 year = {1982}
}

@article{Zhong,
 author = {X. Zhong, R.W. Maccormack and  D.R. Chapman},
 title = {Stabilization of the Burnett equations and application to high-altitude     hypersonic flows},
 journaltitle = {AIAA Journal},
 year = {1993}
}

@article{Lockerby,
 title = "High-resolution Burnett simulations of micro Couette flow and heat transfer ",
 journaltitle = "Journal of Computational Physics ",
 year = "2003",
 author = "Lockerby, D.A. and Reese J.M."
}

@article{xu2004,
  title={Microchannel flow in the slip regime: gas-kinetic BGK--Burnett solutions},
  author={Xu, K. and Li, Z.},
  journaltitle={Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
  year={2004}
}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: toc]
[image: main body]
[image: bibliography]

In order to get numbered chapters, sections and subsection (not default in tufte-book class) i've done the following changes to tufte-common.def, changed

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
```

to

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
```

and added

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

All of this compiles "fine", but produces the following errors and warnings

[image: errors]

Questions:

1. The errors seems to have something to do with the changes i made in tufte-common.def, but how else to achieve numbered chapters, sections and subsections?
2. Why doesn't the contents show sections and subsections, isn't that what \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} does?
3. I have to manually delete the test.bbl and test-blx.bib files or add a new entry to the bibTest.bib file to update the bibliography, i.e. changes I've done in the .bib file won't show unless i do this. That can't be right can it?
4. The bibliography is not ordered in the order they are cited and vice versa, I would prefer that the first citation in my text appear as [1], the second number as [2] etc. Not the way they do now, [1],[3],[2],[4]. I know that biblatex has options for sorting and different cite styles, but non of my efforts has yielded the results I'm looking for. Surely there must be a way to achieve references ordered in ascending order? I've also tried using baceknd=biber but that only produces more error messages.
5. Does anyone have any experience with the warning? Interpretations and ideally a way to fix them.

Additional information:
Using tufte-book class v3.5.0, MiKTeX 2.9 and Sublime Text 2.0.2 as text editor.

I realize this is a rather long post with many questions so I will be very grateful for answers to any or all of my questions :)

Comment: Solved #2, \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} needs to be set in the tufte-book.cls file instead of tufte-common.def

Comment: There is no need to change  tufte-book.cls unless you want all of your documents using that class to look that way. You can change that in your own document, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example compiles fine, despite the erros, with the following (you may have forgotten `\tableofcontents`):

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}  
\addbibresource{testBib.bib}    


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}


\title{A simple document}
\author{An author}



\begin{document}


\maketitle

\tableofcontents


\chapter{chapter}  
Some text~\cite{bobylev}.  

\section{section}  
Lots and lots of more text~\cite{Zhong}.  
\subsection{subsection}  
Delicious yummy text~\cite{xu2004}. OmNomNom~\cite{Lockerby}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It seems that `natbib`, which Tufte classes use, is incompatible with `biblatex`, so that the error messages will not go away, although it compiles fine (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12047/is-biblatex-compatible-with-revtex)).

As to your question #4, `sorting=none` does the trick.

Comment: o @Joseph: Could you possibly add an explanation of the relevance of natbib? Maybe I'm the only one puzzled by this but it is not obvious to me... [Why do I suddenly have to type a letter before I can use an @ symbol?]

Comment: Yes forgot \tableofcontents in my example :) thank you very much for your suggestions, will try them out tomorrow, to tired now. Will post update on how it went

Comment: @cfr, natbib is called by Tufte-LaTeX, see updated answer.

Comment: @Joseph, Ah, thank-you. I looked in the .cls file but it seems it is squirrelled away in tufte-common.def.

Comment: Your solution for wuestion #4 worked like a charm, thank you very much. Natbibs incompatability with Biblatex probably explains #3 as well

Comment: @user2912781, if the answer worked, you can upvote it or set it as solved.

Comment: Couldn't upvote as that required 15 reputation, which i don't have, but accepted the answer, again, thanks for the help