# Label not working after \appendix with revtex4-1

Tags: cross-referencing, revtex

I need to use labels in appendices with revtex4-1 but I've got a "LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references" and the references are not placed. It seems that there's a conflict with biblatex because if I remove the package, references are showing up. But I've got the same result if I remove the "twocolumn" option... Here's a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{natbib}
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\let\textcite\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@natbib.sty\endcsname\relax

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{}

\section{Intro}
\cite{citation}\lipsum[1] \autoref{appen}

\printbibliography

\appendix

\section{Appendix} \label{appen}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

And "biblio.bib" :

```
@article{citation,
title = "test",
journal = "test",
volume = "test",
pages = "test",
year = "test",
author = "test",
}
```

I don't know what to think of this problem so I seek your help. Thanks.

Comment: There indeed seems to be a serious incompatibility with `biblatex`. Not only does `\autoref` not work anymore: not even `\ref` works anymore. :-(

Comment: Just a remark: You don't have to load `natbib`, because `revtex4-1` automatically does.

Comment: Thanks for the remark Henri. I find it strange that they are incompatibilities between `biblatex` and `revtex4-1` because in the APS journals, citations are exported in `bibtex` so I thought that it was recommended to use bibtex.

Comment: Note that there is a *big* difference between `biblatex` and BibTeX (notice the "la"). If `revtex4-1` loads `natbib` there is no chance you are ever going to use `biblatex`. So you will have to use the traditional approach of `\bibliography` and `\bibliographystyle` and not `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography`.

Comment: It's weird because I don't have this problem if I compile with an other computer. Despite this one is running with Debian 7 and the other with Debian 8, the packages are the same (?) so I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @ParmanA can you clarify your last statement - you are able to compile this exact MWE on a machine?  I think it should fail as per moewe's comment.  `revtex` loads `natbib` which is incompatible with `biblatex` so the MWE should always fail (to the best of my knowledge) as per [Is biblatex compatible with RevTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12047/106162)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, I'm not able to compile this exact MWE. However, with an other tex file, I don't have this problem. I've checked it today and I've found that it's not that simple : if you change just a little bit of text, the problem appears.