# Is Biblatex still incompatible with natbib?

Tags: biblatex

I like the idea of Biblatex but I wonder if I can use it in my work for publication.  On my latest look at the problem I found

[Is biblatex compatible with RevTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12047/is-biblatex-compatible-with-revtex)

An answer to it from 2011 says `biblatex` is incompatible with `natbib` and the `biblatex`' `natbib` option only provides aliases for `natbib`'s citation commands.

I suspect all this is still true since just last month a [package](http://tug.org/pkg/biblatex-phys) came out providing a fix for this problem in some cases (it works for the guidelines of the AIP and APS).

So, is it still true?  Is `biblatex` still incompatible with `natbib`?

Comment: Yes. And this will never change. There is absolutly no reason why you would want to use natbib along with biblatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not understand.  Why did someone create the fix provided by biblatex-phys if there is no problem?

Comment: The latest release of `biblatex-phys` fixes some issues in the style but this does not directly relate to `natbib` (it's the same as if there were an issue in the REVTeX styles: things go wrong and have to be fixed).

Comment: Also note that `biblatex-phys` was written some time ago: the latest update was just a 'normal' bug fix, as happens in any software. (I wrote `biblatex-phys` as it's not so hard to do physical science styles: I also do a chemistry bundle and ones for _Nature_ and _Science_-like formatting.)

Comment: @ColinMcLarty 'Someone' here is _me_! The idea was that people need bibliography style files for a lot more than journal submission (in my area, most journals expect Word not LaTeX anyway). In particular, for theses, reports, grant proposals, _etc._ it's common to 'follow' a journal style. That was the reason for writing the `biblatex-phys` bundle. (If it was only about journal submission, most of the work on BibTeX beyond `cite` and `natbib` would be redundant.)

Comment: @JosephWright Our comments and your answer have crossed each other twice now.  This comment answers my question very well--except that the journals I write for all take LaTeX and Biblatex does have features natbib does not that I would like to use in my journal articles.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Check with the editorial office: depending on their workflow at the 'back end', it may not be important how you set up your sources. (If they work from the PDFs all will be fine: if they process the `.tex` it's different.)

Comment: Unfortunately two good ideas are in conflict: journals should process .tex (and the ones I send to do) and they should use Biblatex.  As an author, rather than programmer, I am confident that these ideas are so good they will one day be brought together though it seems they cannot yet.

Comment: To sum it up: `biblatex` completely substitutes `natbib` and the question should be: Is RevTeX still using natbib instead of the better `biblatex`?

Comment: @Johannes_B   Yes, RevTeX and others use natbib because Biblatex is designed not to achieve one thing that publishers need: It offers no means to finally produce a .tex source file usable without also consulting outside data such as a .bib file.  If Biblatex added such a feature it would become much more usable for publishers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `biblatex` approach to bibliographies is very different from that used by 'traditional' BibTeX, which includes `natbib`. The way that a traditional style works is that BibTeX-the-program reads the `.aux` file (for citations), `.bib` file (for data) and `.bst` file (for style), and write a `.bbl` file containing the formatted output. The latter is then typeset directly in LaTeX (*i.e.* `\bibliography` is a special form of `\input`). When using `biblatex`, in contrast, citation data (from the `.aux` or `.bcf`) is used along with the `.bib` file to give a database-like `.bbl` file. The latter is used by `biblatex` to do formatting *at the LaTeX end* (*i.e.* in LaTeX macros).  In this cases, formatting is driven by a `.bbx` file, which tells LaTeX (not BibTeX) how to do the style. The two approaches are thus *fundamentally different*.

It is possible to write a `.bbx` file which does the same as any given `.bst`. Thus as well as the standard `biblatex` styles, there are styles available which match the BibTeX 'traditional' set. There are also implementations for some journal styles. Included in those is `biblatex-phys`, which implements the AIP and APS styles. As those can *never* be used with `natbib`, and thus not with REVTeX, they are not official and cannot be used to substitute in journal submission. (See [Is biblatex compatible with RevTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12047/is-biblatex-compatible-with-revtex).) (Note that  one can 'unload' `natbib` as discussed in [Is it possible to load biblatex with a class that has already loaded natbib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37076/is-it-possible-to-load-biblatex-with-a-class-that-has-already-loaded-natbib), but this would be a bad idea in any official submission.)

Comment: That is helpful showing how Biblatex achieves things natbib cannot.  But wouldn't it be possible to add a component to Biblatex so that after your writing is done the citation data and the .bib file and the resulting .bbl file could work with LaTeX and a .bbx file to produce a new file that would not be database like but could again make \bibliography a special form of \input?  Publishers would be able to use that, and those of us who have to write for publication could start using the advantages of Biblatex.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I plan to address that in your  [other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331026/can-i-isolate-the-publisher-friendly-aspects-of-biblatex-in-a-file): I didn't have a chance yesterday but will today.