# biber cannot find .bcf - "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX - MikTeX 2.9 - TexMaker

Tags: bibtex, errors, texmaker, biber, miktex2.9

I am facing a rather strange issue when running `bibtex` using `MikTeX 2.9` and `TeXMakeR 4.5` under `windows 7`.

At first I run `pdflatex` and then `bibtex` (as configured in `TeXMakeR` `"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/biber.exe" %`). When invoking `bibtex` I get the following error

> ```
>  INFO - This is Biber 2.7 INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
>
>  ERROR - Cannot find control file 'test.bcf'! - did you pass the
>  "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1
>
>  Process exited with error(s)
> ```

I've searched through various questions in `tex.se` but I couldn't find a solution that could fix my problem. A MWE can be found below along with a sample bib file.

```
\documentclass[aps,prc,reprint,superscriptaddress,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[natbib,hyperref,sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{First Author}
\email[E-Mail: ]{first.author@university.edu}
\author{Second Author} 
\affiliation{Department of \LaTeX, National University}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
    \blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction} \label{Introduction}
    \blindtext[2] \cite{JRCreport,JRCref} \blindtext[3].

\bibliography{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography.bib

```
@TechReport{JRCreport,
author = {Sirakov I. and Becker Bjorn and Capote R. and Kopecky Stefan and Massimi C. and Pronyaev V. G and Schillebeeckx Peter and Trkov Andrej and Zerovnik Gasper},
title = {Evaluation of neutron induced reaction cross sections on gold},
institution = {{EC-JRC-Geel}},
year = {2013},
url = {http://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/handle/JRC78690},
key = {JRC78690},
}

@TechReport{JRCref,
author = {L.R. Greenwood and Alan L. Nichols},
title = {Review of the Requirements to Improve and Extend the IRDF library (International Reactor Dosimetry File (IRDF-2002))},
institution = {IAEA},
year = {2007},
url={https://www-nds.iaea.org/publications/indc/indc-nds-0507/},
key = {INDC(NDS)-0507},
}
```

The current configuration of TeXMakeR can be seen here

[image]

I also tried to add the packages

1. `\usepackage[natbib,hyperref,sorting=none]{biblatex}`
2. `\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`
3. `\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`
4. `\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}`

one at a time but I got the following errors when running pdflatex, respectively

1. `! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined`
2. `! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined`
3. `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.`
4. `! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.`

Any idea on what might wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: `revtex` is not compatible with `biblatex`. See [Is biblatex compatible with RevTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12047/2693)

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for your comment. I also tried using `\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}`, which seems to be a package designed for that, but it didn't work.

Comment: The problem is your documentclass `revtex4-1`.  If you must use that class, you cannot use `biblatex`+`biber` you must use `natbib` + `bibtex`.

Comment: @AllanMunn Hmmm... Any idea how to do that?

Comment: See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701) for the basics of what they do.

Comment: @AllanMunn How can I use natbib+bibtex in TexMaker?

Comment: The `revtex` author's guide has some more information. They don't actually mention `natbib` so I'm not sure whether you can use it either.  Do `texdoc auguide` to see that documentation (on most systems).

Comment: For the TexMaker issue, it may be able to use editor directives (see [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101)) or if not, you need to change your `bibtex` preference to `bibtex` instead of `biber`.

Comment: But how would the editor directives help me solve This? I have also tried using bibtex instead of biber but still I cannot make it to build...